# Forcing http on a url using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm using .htaccess to force https on my site and it's working fine. But I need to force http on a single url (example: http://www.website.com?o=com&t=send).
I don't know that how to do this ? I'm not sure how to handle this.

Please help....

Answer (score 1):

You can use this rule as **very first rule just below `RewriteEngine On`** line:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/\?o=com&t=send [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /\?o=com&t=send [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: sorry for my delayed response, but this is not working for me. look at my htaccess code, I think these line cause https `RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www.|$) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L]`

Comment: check my updated rules in a new browser and make sure you have only these 2 rules.

Comment: Great answer; I had a WordPress site running on `https://` and needed to have a URL redirected to a folder without `http://` since it doesn't yet have an SSL (and is really just a landing page).  The importance is in the order of the rules; I had the `http://` redirect at the bottom and this answer stresses that it needs to be the first rule.  Once I changed it, the rule worked.